# This web container has not yet been started @Glassfish 4.0.01 web

Tags: rest, glassfish

so, this is what I'm getting after REST call to my service:

```
[2014-04-25T01:06:52.393+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1398380812393] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[ServletAdaptor]: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1652)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:390)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1128)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:1114)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldName(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
    at som.tepo.helpers.GsonManager.serializeToJson(GsonManager.java:23)
    at som.tepo.srv.InTimeService.getCitiesJson(InTimeService.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
]]`
```

it shows up pretty randomly, sometimes restart helps, sometimes restart of whole os, sometimes Im forced to delete Glassfish as is. Its pretty annoying. What can I do about it?

Comment: I came across the same issue multiple times, as randomly as you get the issue. Have you figured out what was the cause ?

Comment: no, unfortunatelly not yet..
I just have noticed that when I freed up more memory on a disk where my IDE resides (IDEA for me) it was more stable. Althrough I need to confirm this.

Comment: @Andrew might be late but for benefit of other souls, found the problem. It is a result of unreleased EntityManagerFactory that still has a lock on the persistence resources. See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had big trouble resolving this. The problem is that your previous `EntityManagerFactory` was not closed.

Ensure that you always close the EntityManagerFactory upon undeployment. One way to do it is via a registered `ServletContextListener` e.g

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  EntityManagerFactory emf = getEmf(...);
  emf.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you add this to every servlet or some sort of global singleton?

Comment: @MarcelMarino Just one ServletContextListener is enough per your web application

Comment: @MarcelMarino I suppose your EntityManagerFactory is in a singleton

Comment: Does that mean I need to make it not a singleton? Any idea how?

Comment: Wait, IN a singleton? We don't actually use singletons at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a singleton really; the most important concept is that; in JPA, it is recommended to maintain a single EntityManagerFactory per persistence unit(database) because it is resource intensive unlike EntityManager which are lightweight. With that in mind, a singleton or application-scoped bean can be used to hold an instance of EntityManagerFactory. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I think I understand the concept, but not what to do about it. My computer doesn't get these errors (or at least very rarely) while others get them frequently, usually when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Have to checked to make sure you have all of your drivers? It might be that your application can't connect to one of your databases.

Comment: no, no.. with database not running during the deploy you would get different error during the deployment

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your database drivers (JDBC or ODBC) jar file into your glassfish domain lib folder- Glassfish/Domains/Domain1/lib

Comment: Not if `class-loader delegate` is set to `false` in `glassfish-web.xml` or as system property.